# Remover borda de menu material

Tags: css, angular-material

Bom dia, estou usando o menu "Expansion Panel" do [Material](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples) e queria remover a borda da seleção da imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código no momento está assim:

HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header class="sub">

  <mat-panel-title >
     Caderno horas
  </mat-panel-title>

</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

CSS:

```
.sub{
//descobrir como remover a borda
//se colocar cor de fundo funciona mas não remove a borda
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade não é um `border`, é um `box-shadow`, talvez por isso vc não tenha encontrado a borda para remover...

Na classe `.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z])` vc coloca `box-shadow: none`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Considerando o Material atual (2023/24), dentro da sua tag < mat-expansion-panel hideToggle > , você irá acrescentar uma classe : < mat-expansion-panel hideToggle class= "nomedaclasse" > .
No seu arquivo css, irá chamar sua classe:
.nomedaclasse{
box-shadow: none;
}
Caso não funcione, acrescente um !important após o none.